# Cholesterol in Fish higher than in Meats?

Tags: fish, cholesterol

Fish are generally known as food good for cardio-vascular health primarily due to its high Omega-3 content. We also are told that generally cholesterol is bad for cardio-vascular health.

Now I just noticed when I checked nutritional facts that cholesterol in fish could be higher than in meat. For instance, sardines has almost 150mg while pork only has 75mg!

I also heard that there are good and bad cholesterol. Maybe the cholesterol in sardines is the good one while on pork is the bad one?